# odd TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

so i was coding some problems in python in this page
https://www.codewars.com/kata/airport-arrivals-slash-departures-number-1/train/python
the code work fine on my computer but when i update it, i came across this bug.
note that its python 3.4.3

```
def flap_display(lines, rotors):
    baseString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ?!@#&()|<>.:=-+*/0123456789"
    res = []
    baseLen = len(baseString)
    lineLen = len(lines)
    sLen = len(rotors)
    carrier = 0
    for item in range(0 , sLen):
        if (item < lineLen):
            carrier =carrier + rotors[item]
        tmp = baseString.index(lines[item])
        tmp = tmp + carrier
        tmp = tmp % baseLen
        res.append( baseString[tmp] )
    resS = ''.join(res)
    return resS
    print (flap_display("CAT", [1,13,27]))
```

all the website gave me is this:

```
Traceback:
in 
in flap_display
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Now i want to know if my code is incorrect or its just the site being buggy. 
Problem is solved! Thank to mr.kuro

Comment: full stacktrace please

Comment: my bad, i added it

Comment: That's the full traceback?

Comment: You are using `sum` on `rotors[item]`, which I believe an integer. hence the error

Comment: sadly yes, thats what i got from codewar btw, i worked perfectly fine on my computer

Comment: the `sum()` requires list, not int.

Comment: can you tell me more about it mr.kuro?

Comment: Have a look at python built-in function sum. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: mr.sergzach instead of using sum() is there another way to make "carrier =carrier + rotors[item]", that syntax caused bug in my first try

Comment: When I change `carrier =carrier + sum(rotors[item])` to `carrier =carrier + rotors[item]` you code runs perfectly, and outputs `DOG`. So I don't understand why Ahsanul's answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: i first code it correctly in my computer but when i upload the code on codewar (python 3.4.3) it doesnt work and it confused me so much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Referring us to an off-site source for your problem is outside the SO standards.

Comment: BTW, your `print` call isn't indented properly: it should be outside the function, and it's customary to leave a blank line after function definitions.

Comment: Doesn't that codewars site give you a full traceback? If we don't get a proper traceback, and we can't reproduce your problem, then this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

**sum** requires an iterable: a sequence of items, such as a list.  You gave it a single integer.  If you want to add up all the integers in **rotors**, you can do that outside of a loop, with

```
carrier = sum(rotors)
```

More to your code, just add up the items you wanted:

carrier = sum(rotors[:lineLen])

This adds the first **lineLen** elements of **rotors**, allowing you to get rid of that pesky **if** statement.

Can you adapt the rest of the loop logic to take proper advantage of that?

Comment: I think it should be `carrier = sum(rotors[:min(sLen, lineLen)]`

Comment: your suggestion is valuable, but i wonder if you misunderstood my idea a litte bit?

Comment: That's possible, since you didn't explain your "idea".  Your code is undocumented.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/airport-arrivals-slash-departures-number-1/train/python you can try the code by yourself

Comment: @Trinh Cong Minh, in the link you provided, `rotors` is a list with only one element which is in turn a list. In the sample section `rotors = [[1, 13, 27]];` is provided

Answer (score 0):

Thr traceback should be like below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test1.py", line 17, in 
>       print (flap_display("CAT", [1,13,27]))
>     File "test1.py", line 10, in flap_display
>       carrier =carrier + sum(rotors[item])
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

And, as the traceback says, in line

```
carrier =carrier + sum(rotors[item])
```

`rotors[item]` will apparently be an int, so you can't call `sum` on it, hence the Error.

Replace the above line with:

```
carrier = carrier + rotors[item]
```

Or, just skip the loop, and do:

```
carrier = sum(rotors)
```

It should be okay now.

Comment: Im sorry but i cant skip the loop as it a part of my method

Comment: I guess you wrote, `carrier =carrier + rotors`, that will produce the error you just mentioned.

Comment: i assure that i did write it " carrier =carrier + rotors[item] " and it didnt work!?